# android studio Beta 8.9 Error

Tags: java, android-studio

I get this error when I try to build project in android studio:

> Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java" (in
>   directory "C:\Users\magic.AndroidStudioBeta\system\compile-server"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I checked that JAVA_HOME is working correctly. worth mentioning it's actually located in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67`

also I searching around my c drive to see where this error is reported I found in the `/.androidStudioBeta/systemLog/.idea.log`

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\magic\.AndroidStudioBeta\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.startProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:261)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.createProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:248)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.launchBuildProcess(BuildManager.java:953)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.access$1900(BuildManager.java:121)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager$11$2.run(BuildManager.java:666)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
```

Comment: @ZerO your question is probably irrelevant to the OP's question.

Comment: Does this directory/file exist (`C:\Users\magic\.AndroidStudioBeta\system\compile-server`)?

Comment: I am just wondering why he is using a Beta version of AS and then complains about possible bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution

Click Files-> Other Settings -> Default Project structure -> SDK Location -> Change the JDK location there